# Rails project can't connect to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I was trying to create a `rails` project with `postgresql`

I use this

```
>>rails new ReadingList --database=postgresql
>>rails s
```

However, it shows this error [image]

Then, I jump to `psql` and create `readinglist_development` by myself, but it still show the same error.

Comment: How did you create your database? have you tried doing ```rake db:create:all```?

Comment: Your Rails is looking for `ReadingList_development` rather than `readinglist_development`. Check your database.yml in the config directory to change the database name.

Comment: yes, `database: ReadingList_development` is written in `database.yml `

Comment: type `rake db:create` is ok, what is the parameter `:all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails practice, run `rake db:create` to create the database after creating new Rails project.

I believe the name of the database(`readinglist_development`) is not matching the database name of `ReadingList_development` as in `database.yml` which Rails does not recognize the database created using psql.

Comment: yeah, you have been a great help. I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Its better not to create databases form db workbenches, better to use rails db commands.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, I will use rails db command next time.